# Getting posts via WP Query

Tags: wp-query

Here is the scenario, 
There are total 100 posts. In starting on the page, I am displaying 50 posts ( i.e. 1 to 50 ) on the page. There is one Load More button. 
On the click of that Load More button, next 10 posts ( i.e. from 51 to 60 ) should be displayed.
Another click on Load More button, next 10 posts ( i.e. from 61 to 70 ) should be displayed. 
Is there any way to get next few posts via WP Query?

Comment: This is a question made probably hunderds of times; did you try something by yourself? What problems do you have to use `WP_Query`?

Comment: The question is how can I get only posts from 51 to 60, 61 to 70 like that..

Comment: 'offset' => 50, then it's start from 51 post, or you can set 'paged' => 2 and 'posts_per_page' => 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip first 50posts

```
'offset' => 50
```

Pagination

```
'paged' => 2,
'posts_per_page' => 50
```